# Using MMQGIS for geocoding from CSV file?

Tags: qgis, csv, geocoding, mmqgis

I try geocoding locations from a CSV file in QGIS using mmqgis with no success.

1. is there a log file where I can see the error massages?
2. let's use one of the records as an example

When I use the GeoCode plugin and geocode Abu Gosh, Israel - I get the geocode but when I use mmqgis I have no luck. I tried putting country in the state field and city in the address field (I have no address).

Comment: Hello @yair suari, according to the mmqgis documentation found here[http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/] the geocoding with google tool uses the Google Geocoding API. The best place to start figuring out how to amend your inputs for this tool would be to read how that API interprets its inputs.

Comment: Thanks, i willtry that. Though, as i said, when using other implementations of the same api geocoding is successfull.

Comment: It is likely that the other tools you are referencing interact with the API in a different manner, causing the differences you are noticing. Although the API used in both tools is the same, the programing that interfaces with it is most likely different.

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved.
like most others having problems using this plugin i did not understand you must use UTF8 csv files as input.
once this is done-no problem